# How do I change the location of a character in a sentence?

Tags: python

I'm trying to move a character from the beginning of a word to the end of that word.

For example:
input: `_baba _dede`
output `baba_ dede_`

How can I achieve that.

I tried this with `re.sub()`

```
import re
key="_baba _dede"
g=re.sub("_.","._",key)
print(g)
output;
._aba ._ede
```

But it is not working

Comment: There's really no need to use regex for such a simple problem. Try using standard string manipulation tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex. Pattern `re.sub(r"_(\w*)", r"\1_", string)`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "_baba _dede"
print(re.sub(r"_(\w*)", r"\1_", s))
```

**Output:**

```
baba_ dede_
```

Answer (score 3):

a solution without regex

```
text = "_baba _dede"
print [word[1:] + word[0] for word in text.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this, just split the words, remove the underscore from front and put it in the back

```
key="_baba _dede"
li = [ item.replace('_','')+'_' for item in key.split()]
print(' '.join(li))
```

Output is

```
baba_ dede_
```

Or restructure the word to move the character in the front towards the back

```
key="_baba _dede"
li = [ item[1:] + item[0] for item in key.split()]
print(' '.join(li))
```

Output

```
baba_ dede_
```